# how to get column total without resetting indexes in panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[image: This is the dataframe]
and the way I want to display it is something like this

```
                                   ComoQty
DocDate ImportType ForeignType
April   Export     Costal        901637.68
                   Foreign      3258010.20
        Import     Costal        271716.22
                   Foreign      6037122.41
        NET                     <total of export-import>
TOTAL                           <total of the above values of export and import>
```

Is this possible in any way in pandas or is there any different method to achieve the similar goal in any different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter for export/import and compute the sums, assuming the dataframe is called `df`:

```
difference = df[df.ImportType=='Export'].ComoQty.sum()\
            -df[df.ImportType=='Import'].ComoQty.sum()
```

and accordingly with `+` for the total.